# Calculating the determinant of $A$ with $A_{ij}=a$ for $i<j$, $A_{ij}=-a$ for $i>j$, $A_{ii}=x$, using a pen and paper

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

Let

$$A = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
x&a&a&a&\dotsm&a\\
-a&x&a&a&\dotsm&a\\
-a&-a&x&a&\dotsm&a\\
-a&-a&-a&x&\dotsm&a\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
-a&-a&-a&-a&\dotsm&x
\end{array}\right].$$

How would one calculate the determinany of this matrix using a pen and paper? Using cofactors is rather computationally intensive; there must be some way to take advantage of the symmetry in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the determinant by using elementary row operations. Subtract, *simultaneously*, the first row from the second row, the second row from the third row, etc., we can reduce $A$ to
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
x&a&a&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&a\\
-x-a&x-a&0&0&\dots&\cdots&0\\
0&-x-a&x-a&0&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
0&0&-x-a&x-a&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&-x-a&x-a&0\\
0&0&\cdots&\cdots&0&-x-a&x-a
\end{array}\right].
$$
So, if we define $D_n$ to be the determinant of $A$ when its size $n\times n$, then by Laplace expansion along the last column, you can obtain a certain recurrence relation for $D_n$. Solving it, you should get
$$
D_n = \frac{(x+a)^n + (x-a)^n}2.
$$

Comment: I'm getting $D_n = (x-a)D_{n-1} + a(x+a)^{n-1}$, which I'm having trouble getting into your format.

Comment: In particular, I note that $D_2 = x^2 + a^2$ is irreducible.

Comment: I end up with $D_n=x(x-a)^{n-3}(x^2+3a^2) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-3} a(x+a)^{n-i}(x-a)^{i-1}$. That doesn't look correct to me, but I don't see my error.

Comment: @user169845 The recurrence relation you obtained is correct. To prove that the solution is the one given in my answer, you may use mathematical induction. (Surely you can derive it directly, but that is more involved and more tedious.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1**. Try to find eigenvalues.

**Hint 2**. If your matrix is anti-symmetric then what can you say about eigenvalues?